# Why open function doesn't interpret the option of my command every time?

Tags: perl

I want to use `open` function to run the following commands:

```sh
> echo "toto\ntata"
toto
tata
> echo -e "toto\ntata"
toto
tata
> echo -E "toto\ntata"
toto\ntata
> echo -n "toto\ntata"
toto\ntata
```

Note that for the last command, there is no trailing new line.

So I have the following script:

```perl
use strict;

sub run_cmd {
    my ($cmd) = @_;
    my $fcmd;

    print("Run $cmd\n");

    open($fcmd, "$cmd |");
    while ( my $line = <$fcmd> ) {
        print "-> $line";
    }
    close $fcmd;
}

eval{run_cmd('echo "toto\ntata"')};
eval{run_cmd('echo -e "toto\ntata"')};
eval{run_cmd('echo -E "toto\ntata"')};
eval{run_cmd('echo -n "toto\ntata"')};
```

But when I run it, I get this results:

```
Run echo "toto\ntata"
-> toto
-> tata
Run echo -e "toto\ntata"
-> -e toto
-> tata
Run echo -n "toto\ntata"
-> toto
-> tataRun echo -E "toto\ntata"
-> -E toto
-> tata
```

We can see the `-n` option is correctly interpreted by `open`, because there is no newline at the end of the text, but it is not the case for the options `-e` and `-E`. Worse, there are printed by `echo`.

Why my options are not interpreted by `open` every time? What should I do to get a correct output?

Comment: What does `which echo` say on your system? Likely "shell-builtin" ... is there also a `/bin/echo`?

Comment: @zdim When I run this command, I get `/bin/echo`. The result is the same when I run it in the shell or with my `run_cmd` perl function.

Comment: Thank you -- yeah, they behave the same for these options any way ...

Comment: POSIX doesn’t define _any_ options for `echo`, so don’t rely on them. Surely you’re not planning to use `echo` like this anyway, since there’s nothing it does that you can’t do in plain Perl?

Comment: @zdim Indeed, if I explicitly write `/bin/echo -e "toto\ntata"`, the command behaves as expected. So, which `echo` is called by default?

Comment: That's the problem with all the details ... I don't know, specially not on your system. In many other situations that particular command shouldn't make it start a shell, so then you'd be running `/bin/echo`; but I'm not sure how piped open does it. But I'd seriously recommend to use modules for these kinds of things -- it is often notoriously difficult to get it all right. There are modules to run external commands and some to quote things, like `String::ShellQuote`.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you provide a shell command to `system`, `qx`, `open`, etc, it is treated as a `sh` shell command.

---

Here's the documentation for the `echo` builtin of `dash` which is used by some Linux distros as `sh`:

> `echo [-n] args...`
>
> Print the arguments on the standard output, separated by spaces.  Unless the `-n` option is present, a newline is output following the arguments.
>
> If any of the following sequences of characters is encountered during output, the sequence is not output.  Instead, the specified action is performed:
>
> ...
>
> `\n` Output a newline character.
>
> ...

It has no `-e` or `-E` option.

Running the commands from `dash` (aka `sh` in your case) results in exactly the same output as you received.

```
$ echo "toto\ntata"
toto
tata
$ echo -e "toto\ntata"
-e toto
tata
$ echo -E "toto\ntata"
-E toto
tata
$ echo -n "toto\ntata"
toto
tata$
```

---

Your test was probably run in the `bash` shell. The following will execute the command using `bash` instead:

```
open(my $pipe, "-|", "bash", "-c", $cmd)
```

Comment: I'm surprised that `echo` can have a different behavior on `sh` and `bash` (and the man page don't talk about it).
Also, why my code is working when I only add `/bin/` before the call of `echo`?

Comment: `/bin/echo` executes that program. (Documented in `man echo`.) /// `echo` from with `sh` uses `sh`'s builtin `echo`. (Documented in `man sh`.) /// `echo` from with `bash` uses `bash`'s builtin `echo`. (Documented in `man bash`.)

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you use **external** program **echo** when perl has many ways to output some information to the console/file?

At your disposition you have **[print](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html)**, **[printf](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html)**, **[say](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html)**

[Perl input and output functions](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/index-functions-by-cat.html#Input-and-output-functions)

[Programming Perl](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl2/prog/index.htm)